# Remove XML nodes with XQuery in a shell

Tags: xml, shell, xquery, xidel

Sample XML:

```
<outerTag>
  <innerElement>
    <Id>1234</Id>
    <fName>Kim</fName>
    <lName>Scott</lName>
<customData1>Value1</customData1>
<customData2>Value2</customData2>
    <position>North<position>
    <title/>
  </innerElement>
  <innerElement>
    <Id>5678</Id>
    <fName>Brian</fName>
    <lName>Davis</lName>
<customData3>value3</customData3>
<customData4>value4</customData4>
<customData5>value5</customData5>
    <position>South<position>
    <title/>
  </innerElement>
</outerTag>
```

Expected output:

```
<outerTag>
  <innerElement>
    <Id>1234</Id>
    <fName>Kim</fName>
    <lName>Scott</lName>
    <customData1>Value1</customData1>
    <customData2>Value2</customData2>
    <position>North<position><title/></position>
  </position>
  </innerElement>
</outerTag>
```

**I know I can just use the good select `Xpath` to do the trick, but I try to figure how to properly `delete` using `XQuery` and [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel)**.

I tried from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62264508/465183):

```
xidel --xml -e '
    let $element := //innerElement[not(Id["1234"])]
    declare function local:process-xml ($element) {
        $element update delete node
    }
' file.xml
```

I get:

```
An unhandled exception occurred at $00000000006174CA:
ERangeError: Range check error
  $00000000006174CA
  $000000000061782C
  $0000000000629536
  $000000000062E638
  $000000000055C12B
```

Or

```
$ xidel --xquery '
    let $element := //innerElement[./not(Id["1234"])]
    declare function local:process-xml ($element) {
        $element update delete node                                                  
    }
' file.xml
```

I get the same error.

Or with [pure XQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76086802/465183):

```
$ xidel --xml --xquery '
    let $input := /outerTag
    modify delete node $input/innerElement[Id ne "1234"]
    return $input
' file.xml
```

I get error:

```
Error:
err:XPST0003: Missing whitespace or symbol
in line 2 column 5
    modify delete node $input/innerElement[Id ne "1234"]
    ^^^^  error occurs around here
```

Frustrating `xidel` can't handle this pure `XQuery` solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pure XQuery solution, tested in BaseX 10.5

**XQuery**

```
declare context item := document {
<outerTag>
    <innerElement>
        <Id>1234</Id>
        <fName>Kim</fName>
        <lName>Scott</lName>
        <customData1>Value1</customData1>
        <customData2>Value2</customData2>
        <position>North</position>
        <title/>
    </innerElement>
    <innerElement>
        <Id>5678</Id>
        <fName>Brian</fName>
        <lName>Davis</lName>
        <customData3>value3</customData3>
        <customData4>value4</customData4>
        <customData5>value5</customData5>
        <position>South</position>
        <title/>
    </innerElement>
</outerTag>
};

copy $input := .
modify delete node $input/outerTag/innerElement[Id ne "1234"]
return $input
```

**Output**

```
<outerTag>
  <innerElement>
    <Id>1234</Id>
    <fName>Kim</fName>
    <lName>Scott</lName>
    <customData1>Value1</customData1>
    <customData2>Value2</customData2>
    <position>North</position>
    <title/>
  </innerElement>
</outerTag>
```

**XQuery #2**

With file name as a parameter

**Windows Version**:

```
declare base-uri 'e:\Temp\';
declare option db:stripws "true";

copy $input := doc("input.xml")
modify delete node $input/outerTag/innerElement[Id ne "1234"]
return $input
```

**Linux Version**:

```
copy $input := doc("/tmp/file.xml")
modify delete node $input/outerTag/innerElement[Id ne "1234"]
return $input
```

Answer (score 2):

Xidel does not support "XQuery Update". See [mailinglist discussion](https://sourceforge.net/p/videlibri/mailman/message/37064215/).
And as a side note: Although it's possible to edit XML with Xidel, it doesn't aim to be a fully fledged editor. Benito created Xidel to be an extractor in the first place.

You *could* use `transform()`, but the wiki hasn't been updated in ages and the function is deprecated at the moment:

```bash
$ xidel -s file.xml -e '
  transform(
    /,
    function($x){
      if (name($x)="innerElement" and $x/Id="5678")
      then ()
      else $x
    }
  )
' --output-node-format=xml --output-node-indent
pxp:transform(..) is deprecated, use x:transform-nodes(..)
<outerTag>
  <innerElement>
    <Id>1234</Id>
    <fName>Kim</fName>
    <lName>Scott</lName>
    <customData1>Value1</customData1>
    <customData2>Value2</customData2>
    <position>North</position>
    <title/>
  </innerElement>
</outerTag>
```

Instead I'd recommend [`x:replace-nodes()`](https://www.benibela.de/documentation/internettools/xpath-functions.html#x-replace-nodes), which is much easier to use:

```bash
$ xidel -s file.xml -e 'x:replace-nodes(//innerElement[Id="5678"],())' \
  --output-node-format=xml --output-node-indent
```

Comment: @Gilles Quénot Relevant [mailinglist discussion](https://sourceforge.net/p/videlibri/mailman/message/37801670/) with potential wiki-material on `x:replace-nodes()`. I promised Benito I would update the wiki some day, but... that will take some time.

Comment: I edited the [github's wiki page](https://github.com/benibela/xidel/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions/_compare/58ff9e1cbcd1e422291359f1efcd670a07b32637...93f72cfcbf08d9f3065aa9e4cdd7c295fa5887da)

Answer (score 0):

Tried example from [`xidel` doc](https://github.com/benibela/xidel/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#deletion-of-nodes):

```
$ xidel --xml -e '
    let $delete := //innerElement[not(Id="1234")]
    return transform(/, function($e){ $e[not($delete[$e is .])]})
'  file.xml
```

Looks a bit complex.

**Edit: this syntax is now deprecated.**

Will accept another answer if this could be simplified or **using plain pure XQuery [as this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76086802/465183)**.